# Proof that $\det(A) = 0$ implies linear dependence of columns of a matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. How would you rigorously prove that $\det(A) = 0$ if and only if the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent?

Comment: What is your definition of determinant?

Comment: The standard definition presented in a first course in linear algebra

Comment: ...and that is? (Generally there is no standard definition of anything in a first course)

Comment: This definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#n.C2.A0.C3.97.C2.A0n_matrices

Comment: "Rigorously" I'd say the only way to prove that is by means of multilinears alternanting functions, of which the determinant is one of.

Comment: @DavidShoemaker That's one of the more difficult definitions to work with. It wasn't the one in my first linear algebra class.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two possibilities. One is geometric.  If the columns of a square matrix are linearly dependent, the image of the unit cube under the transformation has measure zero, so $\det(A) = 0$.

Here is another.  If two matrices are row equivalent, they both have zero or non-zero determinant. IF the columns of a matrix are linearly dependent, it is of less than full rank (Remember: column rank = row rank). Hence is is row equivalent to a matrix with a zero row (or column if you wish).  In either event, its determinant is zero.

Comment: I've never seen the geometric explained before.  That was great!!  +1

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that $\det(A)=\text{"product of the eigenvalues of $A$"}$:
$$
\begin{gather}
\text{$A$ has linearly dependent columns}\\
\Updownarrow\\
\text{$Ax=0$ for some $x\neq 0$}\\
\Updownarrow\\
\text{0 is an eigenvalue of $A$}\\
\Updownarrow\\
\det(A)=0
\end{gather}
$$
This is not really elementary way how to prove that (using the properties of the determinant with respect to the elementary row/column operations and the row echelon form), it is one of the simplest proofs and still rigorous enough.