# Why $a \in GL(n,K) \Leftrightarrow$ rows of a is basis of $K^n$.

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

So, why is $a \in \mathrm{GL}(n,K)$  $\Leftrightarrow$ the rows of $a$ are a basis of $K^n$.
Trying to prove it, but why a basis of the vector space should make up a matrix in $\mathrm{GL}(n,K)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This answer is for the *columns* instead of *rows*, but $a^\top$ switches columns and rows and is invertible (hence in $\mathrm{GL}(n,K)$) if and only if $a$ is invertible (hence in $\mathrm{GL}(n,K)$). So this makes no difference.

Note that a matrix maps a vector into the span (linear hull) of its columns:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&\cdots &a_{1n}\\
\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
a_{n1}&\cdots &a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \\\vdots \\v_n
\end{pmatrix}
=v_1 \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} \\\vdots \\a_{1n}
\end{pmatrix}
+\cdots+v_n \begin{pmatrix}
a_{n1} \\\vdots \\a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So if the columns are not a basis, they do not span the whole space. The matrix maps a vector to a linear combination of its columns, so the vector gets only maped to a proper subspace of $K^n$ of dimension $<n$. You probably know that a linear map to a proper subspace is not invertible, hence not in $\mathrm{GL}(n,K)$.

This also works the other way around. If a matrix is not invertible it maps to a proper subspace of $K^n$. This subspace is the span of the columns. So the columns cannot be a basis.

Answer (score 0):

1) By definition $GL(n,K)$ is the [group of invertible matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group).

2)  A matrix is [invertible iff its determinant is not null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#The_invertible_matrix_theorem).

3) The determinant of a matrix is not null iff the rows (of columns) of the matrix [are linearly independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant).

4) $n$ linearly independent vectors in $ K^n$ are a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_%28linear_algebra%29#Definition) for the vector space.

Comment: Thank you, but why if det $\ne 0$ then rows are linesrly independent?

Comment: I think this only shifts the question to another domain. Why are the rows not a basis if $\mathrm{det} \not=0$.

Comment: Because they will be dependent.

Comment: @EugeneKorotkov.  For an ''intuitive'' proof you can see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585143/proof-that-deta-0-implies-linear-dependence-of-columns-of-a-matrix-a